# SVG animation not working with static folder / parcel

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, npm, static

Whilst trying to get my SVG to appear in the browser when uploading to my domain, I - similar to other projects where I had **parcel** installed - created a **static folder** where I would put the SVG file into. It now appears in the browser, however, the "drawing" animation that was playing stopped working. So on click of the tour buttons, the SVG appears on both localhost and my domain URL, however, I need it to play the animation, which it doesn't at the moment. It stopped once I created the folder so I'm guessing I'm either linking to it the wrong way or something else that I don't know how to control because I haven't changed anything in my code.

Is there anyone who knows a bit more about this and could help me out?

This is how I am linking to the svg file

```
<section id="tours">        
    <template class="tourTemplate">
        <div id="singleTourArea">
            <h1 class="tourTitle"></h1>
            <p class="tourText"></p>
        </div>  
    </template>
    <div id="tourArea"></div>
    <img id="boatSvg" class="show" src="static/newBoat_1.svg" alt=""> 
</section>
```

And these are the contents of the file:

```
<svg data-name="Layer 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384.43 405.06">
  <path d="M.5.01l1.49 275.61a1231.94 1231.94 0 00162.75 6.17 26.77 26.77 0 01-15.8-25.84 763.46 763.46 0 00138.89-.76 454.68 454.68 0 00-59.35 3.76 1196.94 1196.94 0 01-4-139.55c24.59 37.55 49.46 78.3 49.29 123.19l-121.1 5.58a94.8 94.8 0 0044.81-24.5c5.79-5.67 10.92-12.25 13.52-19.92 1.95-5.76 2.39-11.91 2.81-18l4.86-69.8 8.92 127.37c.28 4 .77 8.41 3.78 11 2.14 1.85 5.11 2.37 7.91 2.75a176.48 176.48 0 0047.66-.1c.12 9.54-7.31 17.87-16 21.78s-18.51 4.31-28 4.65l-87.63 3.1c58.85-18.18 122-18.59 183-9.92 7.27 1 15 2.41 20.37 7.43 5.95 5.55 7.6 14.19 8.93 22.21q8.19 49.37 16.37 98.72" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
```

*CSS* animation:

```
#boatSvg {
  width: 220px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.boatAnimation {
  stroke-dasharray: 3000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3000;
  animation: draw 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```
function showTours(tours) {
    const tourTemplate = document.querySelector(".tourTemplate").content;
    const tourArea = document.querySelector("#tourArea");
    
    tours.forEach((oneTour) => {
        const tourCopy = tourTemplate.cloneNode(true);

        tourCopy.querySelector(".tourTitle").textContent = oneTour.title.rendered;
        const tourText = tourCopy.querySelector(".tourText");
        tourText.innerText = oneTour.description;

        //Expand single tour
        tourCopy.querySelector(".tourTitle").addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (tourText.style.display === "block") {
                tourText.style.display = "none";
                
                document.querySelector("#boatSvg").classList.add("show");
                document.querySelector("#boatSvg").classList.remove("boatAnimation"); 
                document.querySelector("#singleTripArea:nth-of-type(5n)").classList.remove("flashAnimation"); 
                document.querySelector("#singleTripArea:nth-of-type(3n)").classList.remove("flashAnimation");
                document.querySelector("#singleTripArea:first-of-type").classList.remove("flashAnimation");
                } else {
                tourText.style.display = "block";
                  
                document.querySelector("#boatSvg").classList.remove("show");
                document.querySelector("#boatSvg").classList.add("boatAnimation"); 
                document.querySelector("#singleTripArea:nth-of-type(5n)").classList.add("flashAnimation"); 
                document.querySelector("#singleTripArea:nth-of-type(3n)").classList.add("flashAnimation");  
                document.querySelector("#singleTripArea:first-of-type").classList.add("flashAnimation");  
                }
        })
        tourArea.appendChild(tourCopy);
    })
}
```

Comment: @RobertLongson please check the updated code. Basically, I didn't feel the need to include it before since it was all working until I put the svg code into a separate file/folder, so I'm assuming it has something to do with that, and not the animation.

Comment: This won't work this way. You can't apply a class to the contents of an img element i.e. boatAnimation

Comment: @RobertLongson how else should I do it then? I would like to apply that animation to the svg.

Comment: Go back to doing it the way you were doing previously perhaps. Or alternatively use an object or iframe (but then you'd need to inject the changes you need into the object/iframe document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an svg file to html using the `<img>` tag, it cannot accept styling changes from external CSS.
You can solve this problem by adding css styles inside the svg file.

Next, you can post this modified SVG file to your server or local folder on your computer and add it to your application's Html using the  tag.

I don't remember exactly, but `Chrome` seems to disallow calling localhost files for security reasons. Therefore, you need to check the functionality using `Firefox`

```html
<svg data-name="Layer 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384.43 405.06">
<!-- Add styles inside the SVG file -->
 <style>
 #boatSvg {
  width: 220px;
  justify-content: center;
}
#boatAnimation {
  stroke-dasharray: 1901;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1901;
  animation: draw 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
</style> 
 <path id="boatAnimation" d="M.5.01l1.49 275.61a1231.94 1231.94 0 00162.75 6.17 26.77 26.77 0 01-15.8-25.84 763.46 763.46 0 00138.89-.76 454.68 454.68 0 00-59.35 3.76 1196.94 1196.94 0 01-4-139.55c24.59 37.55 49.46 78.3 49.29 123.19l-121.1 5.58a94.8 94.8 0 0044.81-24.5c5.79-5.67 10.92-12.25 13.52-19.92 1.95-5.76 2.39-11.91 2.81-18l4.86-69.8 8.92 127.37c.28 4 .77 8.41 3.78 11 2.14 1.85 5.11 2.37 7.91 2.75a176.48 176.48 0 0047.66-.1c.12 9.54-7.31 17.87-16 21.78s-18.51 4.31-28 4.65l-87.63 3.1c58.85-18.18 122-18.59 183-9.92 7.27 1 15 2.41 20.37 7.43 5.95 5.55 7.6 14.19 8.93 22.21q8.19 49.37 16.37 98.72" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

Added launch of animation by clicking on the canvas

```html
<svg id="svg1" data-name="Layer 3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384.43 405.06">
<!-- Add styles inside the SVG file -->
 <style>
 #boatSvg {
  width: 220px;
  justify-content: center;
}
#boatAnimation {
  stroke-dasharray: 1901;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1901;
 
} 

</style> 
 <path id="boatAnimation" d="M.5.01l1.49 275.61a1231.94 1231.94 0 00162.75 6.17 26.77 26.77 0 01-15.8-25.84 763.46 763.46 0 00138.89-.76 454.68 454.68 0 00-59.35 3.76 1196.94 1196.94 0 01-4-139.55c24.59 37.55 49.46 78.3 49.29 123.19l-121.1 5.58a94.8 94.8 0 0044.81-24.5c5.79-5.67 10.92-12.25 13.52-19.92 1.95-5.76 2.39-11.91 2.81-18l4.86-69.8 8.92 127.37c.28 4 .77 8.41 3.78 11 2.14 1.85 5.11 2.37 7.91 2.75a176.48 176.48 0 0047.66-.1c.12 9.54-7.31 17.87-16 21.78s-18.51 4.31-28 4.65l-87.63 3.1c58.85-18.18 122-18.59 183-9.92 7.27 1 15 2.41 20.37 7.43 5.95 5.55 7.6 14.19 8.93 22.21q8.19 49.37 16.37 98.72" fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-miterlimit="10">
     <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
      begin="svg1.click"
      dur="5s"
      to="0"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much! That's good to know :)

Comment: @MéganeLondoño Thank you for your positive feedback! Added another example. Maybe an additional plus :)